# Проблема с таблицей Менделеева

Tags: html

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы `24` и `Cr` находились в одной ячейке и `24` была в левом верхнем углу. И как мне сделать так, чтобы получить таблицу из таких ячеек?

```
<table border=2>
<tr><th>24</th><td colspan=2 style="font-size:33px" text align=center>Cr</td></tr>
<td><th>24</th><td colspan=2 style="font-size:33px" text align=center>Cr</td>
```

| 24 | Cr |
| --- | --- |
|  | 24 | Cr |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<sup></sup> - верхний индекс
<sub></sub> - нижний индекс
```

Answer (score 1):

| 24 cr |
| --- |
|  | 24 | cr |

Answer (score 0):

```
<table  border="1">
<tr>
<td valign="top" align="left">24</td>
<td align="center"><br />Cr</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center">
24 Cr
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

| 24 | Cr |
| --- | --- |
| 24 Cr |

Comment: Нет. Надо чтоб они были в одной ячейке, а 24 находилась вверху слева.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table  border="1" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
 <td valign="top" align="left">24</td>
<td align="center"><br />Cr</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center">
<sup>24</sup> Cr
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Результат:**

| 24 | Cr |
| --- | --- |
| <sup>24</sup> Cr |

Чуть переделал ранний пост =)